# Error in ARIMAProcess example

Tags: bugs, data-structures, stochastic-calculus

I am trying to compile the sample of ARIMAProcess of MMA [here](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/time-series-and-stochastic-differential-equations/forecast-exchange-rates.html) .It doesn't work.What is wrong?Could you please help?I am using exact same code.

```
data = TemporalData[FinancialData["EUR/USD", {{2012, 5, 1}, {2012, 9, 30}}]]["Part",All, {{2012, 5, 1}, {2012, 9, 30}}];
DateListPlot[data["Path"], Joined -> True, Filling -> Bottom, ImageSize -> 350]
eproc = EstimatedProcess[data, ARIMAProcess[40, 2, 0]]
forecast = TimeSeriesForecast[eproc, data, {20}]
DateListPlot[{data["Path"], forecast["Path"]}, Joined -> True, 
Filling -> Axis, PlotLabel -> "EUR/USD", ImageSize -> 350]
```

Comment: Post the code you are using here?

Comment: @Öskå I add it ok?

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: @Öskå  version 9.0.1

Comment: I think the problem is the FinancialData call. It uses Yahoo Finance and I have noted in the past the results can be flaky (depending on the weather, or whatever. Apparently, today is one of those days). Sometimes it just returns no data. If you retry your code a couple of times you will see it will give you the figure. I just did and I got the intended figure. By the way: don't use the word 'compile' in your question. It does not describe what you did.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I am also getting the figure but not forecast figure.You got all figures??

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries No I am using my own data and getting the same kind of answer.I think there is something wrong somewhere else.You have even forecast figure???!!!

Comment: @Öskå what about you ?everything is alright with you?

Comment: I tried and I also got the forecast. It seems to work once in every three tries for me. I think there is only one call to external data (FinancialData).. so thats strange

Comment: FinancialData succeeded 48 times in 100 calls. But indeed, there's also a failure down the line. `forecast["Path"]` spits out strange dates like `{2012, 9, 3269/104, 0, 0, 0.}`

Comment: @Alex Everything is right for me :) I just wanted to make sure that you didnt use v. 8.x.x. or lower.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I am also using my own data and for forecast and I am getting `::tpspc: The time specification DateList[{2012,12,220591/7019,0,0,0.}] should be one of Automatic, a time range, a list containing a list of explicit times, or a list containing one such specification for each path in the data. >`what wrong???!!It is the same Error for online data.

Comment: interestingly, if you leave out the dates then everything just works fine. something's wrong with the dates...

Comment: @Stefan are you kidding?how?could you please describe?

Comment: @Alex the only thing i did to at least see something was: data = TemporalData[
  Select[FinancialData["EUR/USD", {{2012, 5, 1}, {2012, 9, 30}}], 
    FreeQ[#, Missing] &][[All, 2]]]

at least it looks nearly the same as in the example, except the time axis...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries many thanks for the Andy answer.I dont know why these days I am just confronting MMA bugs.Could you please tell us how can you get result??!! Isn't it strange?

Comment: Not sure why you thank me for Andy's answer...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries you know what I mean :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of known bugs at play here. First, in `TemporalData` the date increment is given as a rational number but some of the underlying date functionality doesn't know how to handle this (e.g. `DateList` doesn't reliably cannonicalize date lists with fractional components).

```
(*As of 9.0.1*)
data = TemporalData[FinancialData["EUR/USD", {{2012, 5, 1}, {2012, 9, 30}}]]["Part",
         All, {{2012, 5, 1}, {2012, 9, 30}}];

data["UnexpandedRawTimes"]

(*{TemporalData`DateSpecification[{2012, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2012, 9, 30, 0, 0, 0.}, 
    {149/104, "Day"}]} *)
```

The more critical issue is that `TemporalData` functionality changed for version 9.0.1 to allow for these date specifications so that a wider array of time specifications could be treated as uniformly spaced. Unfortunately, `TimeSeriesForecast` wasn't updated to reflect the change.

This will all be fixed in future versions but for now the only work around is to work with numeric time stamps rather than dates as @Stefan suggested.

```
data = TemporalData[
   Select[FinancialData["EUR/USD", {{2012, 5, 1}, {2012, 9, 30}}], 
     FreeQ[#, Missing] &][[All, 2]]];

eproc = EstimatedProcess[data, ARIMAProcess[40, 2, 0]];

forecast = TimeSeriesForecast[eproc, data, {20}];

ListPlot[{data["Path"], forecast["Path"]}, Joined -> True, 
 Filling -> Axis, PlotLabel -> "EUR/USD", ImageSize -> 350]
```

[image]

Comment: and i thought that my workaround isn't valuable enough. thank you @Andy. i think it is perfect that you posted the answer, since you know exactly where the final problem lies (TimeSeriesForecast). i didn't. it just did the job...

Comment: @Andy many thanks for the answer.I dont know why these days I am just confronting MMA bugs.@Sjoerd C. de Vries could you please tell us how can you get result??!! Isn't it strange?